# How to copy C: to bigger hard drive without screwing it all up?

Tags: hard-drive

I currently have a 128 GB SSD drive as my C:\. I'm thinking of upgrading to a bigger SSD (i.e. 512 GB if that matters) but I'm worried about the transfer. I've never done a hardware replacement for the OS drive that didn't involve a fresh installation.

I know that if I copy the partitions then I'll end up with a ~120 GB partition that matches my C:\ on the old drive and expanding that partition to take up the rest of the drive space seems unreliable (when I've done it on other non-OS drives, the option to expand was usually grayed out and I had to delete and recreate partitions). Of course I can't just copy over the files as if it was an external drive and expect it to work because I need the MBR to copy over byte for byte in the proper location of the drive. Also I've heard that Windows will invalidate it's license if it detects certain hardware changes (probably because it thinks it was flashed onto a computer as a means of piracy). I'd like to avoid that of course.

Is there an idiot proof way to move all files, registry, MBR, EVERYTHING to a bigger drive and then swap out the hardware and have it just work? Without reinstalling the OS if possible?

Comment: Maybe create System Image of Windows and restore that Image to new drive?

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to use **[Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/)** (Server edition ONLY):

1- Choose **Migrate** OS to SSD/HD wizard.

[image: Partition wizard server UI]

2- Select a destination hard disk and click next.

**ATTENTION:**

- The destination drive will be erased.
- If you had a power failure, you might have a heart attack :) (DATA LOSE)

[image: Migration process]

Answer (score -1):

Imaging should certainly be an option. Linux `dd` would be a better one. Having windows "just work" is a bit optimistic at the best of times.
 - Back up your stuff.
 - boot live linux of your choice
 - `dd if=/dev/old_drive of=/dev/new_drive bs=4096`
 - use your partitioning tool of choice to expand the partition to fill the disk
 - boot new drive, let windows cry about it. You may need to run "recovery options", chkdsk etc.

Comment: Are you sure it won't break Windows? "Letting Windows cry" is certainly not a good option!

Comment: Have any "partitioning tool of choice" recommendations? I guess there's always gparted but I really don't have much experience with any of them.

Comment: That depends on your definition of "broken". To me, windows is already "broken". No I am not certain, which is why step 1 was a backup. Any other OS on the planet would be fine with this process, I cannot guarantee windows will be.

Comment: Go with Bill Oertell's answer, for simplicity.

Comment: "To me, windows is already "broken"." - perhaps you should refrain from answering windows questions then ...